# Plugin templates vs Parent Theme

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, templates

I've been building a plugin using a WooCommerce like template system, where the plugin houses the default templates, but allows for overriding via a template folder in your active theme.
It just occurred to me that another option would be to use a base parent theme just for markup, and then build child themes with different styling options.

I'm trying to figure out what the pros and cons of both approaches are for development and for the user – or if there are other options.

The plugin is designed to be a self contained system, so I could see that being in favor of using a parent theme. But if it ever becomes a plugin that's distributed, I see how using a plugin template system could be more advantageous.

How should I provide the templates needed for my plugin?

Comment: great edit toscho!